# Participle Clause - past particple

Tags: past-tense, participles

1. > As I hadn't finished my assignment, I was very anxious.
   >   = Not having/Having not finished my assignment, I was very anxious.

   Consider changing the sentence:

   > Not finished my assignment, I was very anxious.

   Is it interchangeable and correct? Do the meanings change?
2. > As he hadn't been informed about safety issues, he was very anxious.
   >   = [Having not been/Not having been] informed about safety issues, he was very anxious. (correct?)

   Consider changing the sentence:

   > Not informed about safety issues, he was very anxious.

   Is it interchangeable and correct? Do the meanings change?

Answer (score 0):

"Not finished my assignment" is poor syntax and would be better stated as either "My assignment not yet finished" or by the addition of a preposition, "Not finished *with* my assignment", which is incidentally the structure that you have used in your second example, "Not informed *about* safety issues".

On the other hand, "Having not been informed about safety issues" is well put, although not precisely the same meaning as "Not informed about safety issues", which is also correct.

The difference lies in the fact that the present participle clause you've cited is in the passive voice (to have been informed by someone else), whereas your past participle clause does not make this distinction.  Thus "Having not been informed" would seem to assign blame (e.g., to his employer for not informing him), while saying "Not informed about safety issues" would seem to express his anxiety as a consequence of simply not knowing about safety issues, whether this be due to his own ignorance, his failure to read the safety manual supplied by his employer, or his employer's failure to provide the information to him.

Comment: I revised the question, you can have a look again. I sounded confusing at first

Comment: I stand by my answer, as to the difference in meaning (or specificity) between a passive construction that employs the auxiliary "to be" and one simply negating the past participle (not informed).